# Plants tag changes to Flora

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Whenever I use the Plants tag, it automatically changes it to Flora.  Is this a bug?

Example:

[Personal Plant Survival](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14062/personal-plant-survival)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[plants](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants) is a synonym of [flora](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flora) they are basically the same thing.  The change just keeps things more organized around here.  This way when someone wants to search questions about plants if they select plants OR flora they will get all the questions.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/flora/synonyms